# graphene-django: Query all the models fields and not the requested fields

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have two models:

```
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, related_name="pets", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.type.name} {self.name}'
```

The schema:

```
class Type(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = TypeModel

    @classmethod
    def get_node(cls, info, id):
        return TypeModel.objects.get(id=id)


class TypeConnector(graphene.Connection):
    count = graphene.Int()

    class Meta:
        node = Type

    def resolve_count(root, info):
        return len(root.edges)


class Pet(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = PetModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)

    @classmethod
    def get_node(cls, info, id):
        return PetModel.objects.get(id=id)


class PetConnector(graphene.Connection):
    count = graphene.Int()

    class Meta:
        node = Pet

    def resolve_count(root, info):
        return len(root.edges)


class Schema(ObjectType):
    pets = graphene.ConnectionField(PetConnector)
    types = graphene.ConnectionField(TypeConnector)

    def resolve_pets(self, info, **kwargs):
        # TODO: Query for requested fields only
        return PetModel.objects.all()

    def resolve_types(self, info, **kwargs):
        # TODO: Query for requested fields only
        return TypeModel.objects.all()
```

One of the goals of GraphQL is the performance. To make it the GraphQL must request to the database only the requested fields via GraphQL request (e.g: GraphiQL)

If I request the following query:

```
{
  pets {
    edges {
      node {
        color
        type {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

graphene-django library generate the follow SQL:

```
2020-01-03 03:16:18.184 UTC [136] LOG:  statement: SELECT "pets_pet"."id", "pets_pet"."name", "pets_pet"."color", "pets_pet"."type_id" FROM "pets_pet"
2020-01-03 03:16:18.189 UTC [136] LOG:  statement: SELECT "pets_type"."id", "pets_type"."name" FROM "pets_type" WHERE "pets_type"."id" = 1 LIMIT 21
```

It gets all the fields of the models! Is the same of the API Rest problems and does not conest with the GraphQL guidelines.

If I request the field `color` from the `pets` model I hope that the query will be:

```
SELECT "pets_pet"."color" FROM "pets_pet"
```

And... how does foreign key resolve with this approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [graphene-django-optimizer](https://github.com/tfoxy/graphene-django-optimizer).

What it does is to optmize your query so you fetch all related objects in just one query.

In your case, this could be your resolver:

```py
import graphene_django_optimizer as gql_optimizer

...

class Schema(ObjectType):
    pets = graphene.ConnectionField(PetConnector)
    types = graphene.ConnectionField(TypeConnector)

    def resolve_pets(self, info, **kwargs):
        return gql_optimizer.query(PetModel.objects.all(), info)
```

And it will generate the following queryset automatically:

```py
  Pets.objects
    .select_related('type')
    .only('color', 'type__name')
```